# TFS 2013 Need to remove collection that is stuck being serviced

Tags: tfs

Currently running TFS 2013 Update 4 (12.0.31101.0 (Tfs2013.Update4))

We're trying to upgrade to TFS 2015 and it fails with the error

```
[Error  @18:03:16.990] TF255430: The database Tfs_DefaultCollection was partially upgraded during a failed upgrade. You must restore your data from a backup to its original state to continue.
```

The above database is for the Default Team Project Collection and we don't use it. That collection is offline, and has been for many months. There is nothing in that collection and we have no need to keep it. We just need to remove it as it's blocking our upgrade.

Looking in the Project collection status, I can see that there is an ApplyPatch job that failed. Have tried re-running the job but it continues to return the following failure messages.

```
[18:45:10.700]   Database: Tfs_DefaultCollection, Sql Instance: MDCPTFS02
[18:45:10.967]   [Error] TF400744: An error occurred while executing the following script: CollectionFrameworkDev10ToDev11CTP1.sql. Failed batch starts on the line 336. Statement line: 8. Script line: 343. Error: 1750 Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
[18:45:10.990]   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationServicingException: TF400744: An error occurred while executing the following script: CollectionFrameworkDev10ToDev11CTP1.sql. Failed batch starts on the line 336. Statement line: 8. Script line: 343. Error: 1750 Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Hope someone can provide some ideas on working around this issue.

Cheers
Phil

Comment: Are you unable to Detach Collection from the Team Foundation Server Administration Console? This way the upgrade wizard should stop trying to upgrade it.

Comment: Did you have the backup database for the default Team Project Collection?

Comment: @ToreØstergaard no can't do anything with that collection. I've also tried re-applying the Update 4, but it stops with exactly the same error as the TFS 2015 Upgrade.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, no we don't have a backup of the collection that isn't "broken", as the Project collection isn't being used, it wasn't included in our regular backup retention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the backup database, the simplest and safe way is following the instructions above as “You must restore your data from a backup to its original state to continue”. Restored the collection, re-ran the update and all should works well. Finally, you just need to delete the redundancy collection.

You can also choose to [Detach the Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138(v=vs.100).aspx#Detach) first just as comment suggested and try the update again.

**Update**

If you really don't need that project collection. You can try to **delete** it through command line.

1. On TFS server, open Administrative Command Prompt and change to TFS Tools Directory.

   ```
   %programfiles%\microsoft team foundation server[versionnumber]\tools
   ```
2. Type the command:

   ```
   TFSConfig Collection /delete /collectionName:[COLLECTION NAME]
   ```

Details please refer this blog: [how to delete a Team Project Collection](https://rules.ssw.com.au/do-you-know-how-to-delete-a-team-project-collection)

Then  **delete the collection database** `Open SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the instance of the SQL Server Database Engine that hosts the collection database, and expand the instance.
Highlight the name of the collection database (by default, TFS_CollectionName), and then delete the database.` and  delete the SharePoint site collection that supported the deleted collection.(If you have).

Comment: The Team Project Collection can't even be detached. I get the error, 

`TF401218: The project collection 'DefaultCollection' cannot be detached. The host is in the process of being serviced. The servicing may have failed and needs to be restarted and completed before the host can be detached.`

Comment: If you really don't nee that project collection. You can try to delete it through command line. Details please refer https://rules.ssw.com.au/do-you-know-how-to-delete-a-team-project-collection. Then  delete the collection database `Open SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the instance of the SQL Server Database Engine that hosts the collection database, and expand the instance.
Highlight the name of the collection database (by default, TFS_CollectionName), and then delete the database.` and  delete the SharePoint site collection that supported the deleted collection.(If you have).

Comment: Cheers, that delete option fixed things. Why on earth is it so hard to find this sort of info without having to jump to a third-party website?